# com.google.android.maps.MapView shows out of date map tiles

Tags: android, google-maps

Being new to Android (used to using Bing maps on WP7) I am assuming that the default way in which to put mapping functionality into an Android app is to use the MapView Control - The one on the Map Views tutorial.

Given that, there seem to be something wrong with it...
Using the tutorial Map Views app, the tract where I live initially displayed as being over 7 years old (my tract was still raw land).  Then, a week or so later I ran it again and it was up to date (my house and street were there).  Then,  yesterday I ran it again and it was over 7 years old again and today it is up-to-date again.  What's going on here??  How can I write a quality app with a mapping service like that?

when I use Google maps on the google.com it is always up to date.
Thanks,
Dean

Comment: when you say "tract" what do you mean? Are you looking at satellite map tiles? Or the street map tiles?